# Is it possible to create variables from a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, laravel

I need to convert the content of an email `Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"` to variables and store them in a database so they can be retrieved and output in tables/graphs. 
I'm using Laravel.

I'm using Laravel5.8 with https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap to handle the storing of subject/recipients in the database.

So I need to be able to get the Information from the header and show the table below in variables for example:
`$location = "UNIT 1 PERCH 1";
$subLoc = "House 1, Pen 1;
$age = "3 DAYS";`

I've managed to get the full email stored in the database but it's a bit pointless if I can't manipulate the text.

Sample Email:

```
        123 ADDRESS
      THE ADDRESS
  BW8010 2.55  UNIT 1

Logged   07 JUN 14 23:59

     SUMMARY REPORT

----UNIT 1  PERCH 1-----
     House 1, Pen 1

Age         DAYS       3
Total               3991
Average     GMS       61
Deviation   GMS       16
Evenness    %         22
C.V.        %       21.1
Daily gain  GMS        1

----UNIT 1  PERCH 2-----
     House 1, Pen 2

Age         DAYS       2
Total               3123
Average     GMS       74
Deviation   GMS       16
Evenness    %         12
C.V.        %         34
Daily gain  GMS        2
```

Comment: I think you need to look about regex

Comment: If that is one string and you can't do anything before it is inserted in the database then regex is your friend. But i would focus on fixing the storing process to store it in in different associated columns.

Comment: Do you control the formatting of the email? You could put separators in and make your life a little easier.

Failing that, regex.

Comment: It's basically GSM modems that send emails daily to alert provide data for a particular location. Editing the text would need to be done on thousands of them so that's now an option. I'll look into regex.

Comment: Yes its posible , try one https://packagist.org/?query=mail%20parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `regex`, you can get `location`, `subLoc` and `age` data (**THE MAIL TEMPLATE MUST BE LIKE ABOVE**). I've just grab the first match, If you need all the matches then you can use a `foreach()` to get all of the occurrence,

```
<?php
$re = '/----(.*)-----
     (.*)

Age         (?:DAYS       (\d+))/m';
$str = ' 123 ADDRESS
      THE ADDRESS
  BW8010 2.55  UNIT 1

Logged   07 JUN 14 23:59

     SUMMARY REPORT

----UNIT 1  PERCH 1-----
     House 1, Pen 1

Age         DAYS       3
Total               3991
Average     GMS       61
Deviation   GMS       16
Evenness    %         22
C.V.        %       21.1
Daily gain  GMS        1

----UNIT 1  PERCH 2-----
     House 1, Pen 2

Age         DAYS       2
Total               3123
Average     GMS       74
Deviation   GMS       16
Evenness    %         12
C.V.        %         34
Daily gain  GMS        2';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
$keys = ['location','subLoc','age'];
$values= [$matches[0][1],$matches[0][2],$matches[0][3]];
$result = array_combine($keys,$values);
extract($result);
echo "\$location = $location; \$subLoc = $subLoc; \$c = $subLoc;";
?>
```

**Output:**

```
$location = UNIT 1  PERCH 1; $subLoc = House 1, Pen 1; $c = 3;
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/HiEqI

Comment: This does work if it just a string like above although it's not ignoring the \r\n in the string. Also is there a quicker way to do this? Regex is incredibly slow when there's a lot of text to go through.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this out. But the general idea is you could have an array with all the variable names you would like from the email. Then read the email and for each line loop the array to see if the line contains the name of a variable needed. If it does then save the line to the database. There are probably ways to make this more efficient.

```
  <?php 

  $variableNames = array("Location", "Age"); //Array of variable names to get

  $email = fopen($fileName, "r") or die("Unable to open email"); 

  //For each line of the email
  while(!feof($email ))
  {
    $line = fget($email); //Get the current line

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($variableNames); $i++){ //Loop through the variables array

      if(stristr($line, $variableNames[$i])){ //if the line contains the name of a desired variable
        //Add $line to database...
      }
    }
  }

  fclose($email );
?>
```

Comment: I think he ask how to convert from string, not file ? Btw. if you want convert file lines  to array, then simple $arr = file(my.csv);

Comment: Yes I need to get variables out of a Plain Text email. I get the body of the email out using `$message = $oMessage->getTextBody(true);`